# How to delete a string from a RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, string-matching

I am trying to parse junk and narrow down a bunch of text. How do I delete the current line if a does not match? I would like to remove the line entirely:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
  Dim a As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(i).ToString
  If Not a = "SaveThisLine" Then
    'delete the active line
  End If
Next
```

Also how would I match partially? Such as `if not a = "SaveThisLine" & *` (to use a wildcard).

Comment: For a start, I'd loop in the opposite direction -- For i As Integer = RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1 to 0 Step -1 -- otherwise you'll find you're moving your row elements as you delete lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not touch original text and rather save *valid* lines into a `StringBuilder`, so if line is valid, `AppendLine` to it. In the end dump back into `RichTextBox1.Text` using `StringBuilder.ToString`.

For partial match in VB.NET you can use a native `Like` operator:

```
"aaa" Like "a*"
```

Returns `True`.

Or use regular expressions:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("aaa", "^a").Success
```

Also returns `True`.

Comment: You can also use [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

Comment: thanks for helping me out!  Definitely helped me get to my answer. Now I know about stringbuilder!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way to:

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
        If RichTextBox1.Lines(i) = "2" Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Lines(i), "", , 1)
        End If
    Next
```